# Does "could" always mean something less likely than "can", even in backshifted subordinate clauses?

Tags: modal-verbs, sequence-of-tenses, backshifting, narration

Does the *could* version **always** show more uncertainty/doubt than the *can* version in each of ⑴, ⑵, and ⑶?

> 1. *You **can**/**could** get very nasty skin diseases from bathing in dirty water.*
> 2. *You **can**/**could** get into even worse trouble if you’re not careful.*
> 3. Bobby Reynolds did not win at Wimbledon on Thursday, or did he?
>
>    The scoreboard showed the world № 1 Novak Djokovic defeated Reynolds, 7–6 (2), 6–3, 6–1, on Centre Court, and after winning three qualifying matches and a gutsy five-setter in his opening round, Reynolds’s 2013 singles campaign at the championships was over.
>
>    *He lost to a better player. He won in every other way one **can**/**could** imagine.*

Or could it be that the *could* in ⑶ is simply the past-tense version of *can* so that it matches the past tense used in the two preceding verbs *won* and *lost*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Could* is not always less likely than *can*. Nor is it more likely. It isn't always anything; it's not that simple. In all of the above examples, it **can** (or, if you prefer, **could**) indicate less likelihood; but it can (or could) also indicate something different (like a different set of assumptions to draw conclusions from); and it can (or could) be pretty much indistinguishable from *can*.

A great deal depends on individual usage. People form habits about how and when they use which auxiliaries. In particular how they pronounce them -- intonation matters a **lot** with modals. Consider the many many ways the following sentence can be pronounced, including *suppose* and *could* (not to mention *Well,*):

- *Well, I suppose he could do that.*

One can vary from certain affirmation to vehement denial, depending.

The big mistake is supposing that modals have fixed, simple meanings, like nouns. Auxiliaries are part of the machinery, and modals are far more complex than most engines. Modals are **about** variability, statistics, and individual judgements. They **always** represent somebody's judgement, but whose, and how good it is vary considerably.

Comment: *but it can (or could) also indicate something different (like a different set of assumptions to draw conclusions from)*----Would you please elaborate on this one a little more?

Comment: there are limits to the uses of epistemic _can_; it only occurs in negative environments. You can say _This can't be the place_, but not *_This can be the place._ Mostly epistemic _can_ and _could_ are the same -- "possible" -- but there are a **lot** of ways of being "possible", since it's always a judgement by somebody with limited information, and there are an unbelievable number of kinds of information (most of which we don't understand) that make people decide what's "possible" (not to speak of "likely").